# Why does GNU Screen cause me to have to press Esc twice in Vim?

Tags: vim, gnu-screen

When I launch GNU Screen and then open Vim, to get out of "insert mode", I have to press the Escape key twice, whereas in Vim outside of Screen I only have to press it once.

Why does this happen and how could I change it?

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11382/delay-between-hitting-esc-in-insert-mode-and-switching-to-normal-mode-within

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8439/gnu-screen-makes-vim-esc-key-slow

Comment: Thanks. Does anyone know why this happens in the first place? Why is Screen configured to have a delay in registering the Esc key by default?

Comment: It does that for the exact same reason Vim does it: `<Esc>` is used in many so-called "escape sequences" so the program needs a timeout to decide if `<Esc>` is the start of an escape sequence or if the user really meant to press the `<Esc>` key.

Comment: Ok, awesome, thank you very much for clarification.

Comment: Just an update, those posts helped me reduce the delay between when I press ESC the second time and when Vim actually leaves Insert mode (with `maptimeout`). But they do not mention why I have to press Escape twice still, except one suggestion that Screen is already binding it to something so I should try remapping it. If anyone knows how to do that I'd appreciate hearing about it. Thank you very much

Comment: i fixed it by clearing the `mouse` variable: `set mouse=` (of course, i don't use a mouse in vim)

Answer (score 0):

I think you encounter [bug 57748](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?57748) of GNU Screen. There is a patch available for testing and hopefully included in next version of Screen.

As a workaround I suggest disabling mouse input in `.vimrc`

```
" workaround screen bug with sgr mouse
set mouse=
```